automatic dependency created in package.json everytime I open the project on vscode
Automatic dependency with the file name
I tried removing it and then npm install again. But every time, it comes back.
The inclusion of "-medspa-demo": "file:" in your dependencies is unusual and likely unintended. This entry typically appears when a local package is being referenced, but in this case, it seems to be a mistake or artifact from an incomplete local development setup.
Here's what you should know:
The entry "-medspa-demo": "file:" in your dependencies suggests that the project is trying to reference itself as a dependency, which is generally not correct or necessary.
This kind of entry is often used when developing packages locally and you want to reference a local directory. However, in a normal application setup, you wouldn't need to reference the project itself.
It's possible this was added accidentally during development or when setting up the project structure.
To resolve this:
You should remove the "-medspa-demo": "file:" line from your dependencies in the package.json file.
After removing this line, you should run npm install or yarn install (depending on which package manager you're using) to update your dependency tree.
Make sure that removing this doesn't break any part of your application. If it does, you might need to investigate why your project is trying to reference itself and restructure your code accordingly.
If you're using version control (like Git), commit this change after verifying that your project still works correctly.
This change should help clean up your dependency list and prevent any potential issues that might arise from the project trying to reference itself as a dependency.

This seems like it would be better as a self-answered question. If that's the case, please [edit] the answer out of the question and move it to an independent answer.

This keeps happening because of a bug in the newest version of Red Hat Dependency Analytics extension. You can temporarily fix this by disabling the extension and wait for a new version to be released which includes the bugfix.
The issue is already reported on GitHub.
